# Combine features into one single average feature

Tags: python, pandas

How can we combine three features in a dataset, that have the same traits?

What I mean is: I have energy0, energy1, energy2. How can I combine these into a single feature energy, combining them all into a single average feature?

Comment: Depending on what you want, you might be better off providing all three values to an embedding layer and letting your network learn the best weights to put on these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use pandas library, and the [mean](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html?msclkid=4284d61acf7811ecabe1a1cdb0a0f9a1) function with parameter axis=1

code example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"e1":[1,2,3,4],"e2":[1,2,3,4],"e3":[1,2,3,4]})

average_feature = df[["e1","e2","e3"]].mean(axis=1)
```